# Solution is still in Azure DevOps which is not in repo

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I am struggling with Azure DevOps. I added a project into the solution and then pushed it into Azure Devops. I have now opened the repository in VS - removed the project (as I dont want it in there) and then pushed it back to devops and its still there and i cannot get it removed.

this is my VS Soltution :

[image]

and this is my devops

[image]

Whatever i do I cannot remove the other project from the solution in devops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only removed the project from the solution. It's still there in the file system. To completely remove it from source control, you need to delete it physically, i.e., via Windows Explorer.

Comment: cheers, thanks ! Sorted.